# what does ">>>" mean in java?

Tags: java, arrays, primitive

I found this code to find duplicates in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372385/binary-search-olog-n-algorithm-to-find-duplicate-in-sequential-list?rq=1) post here.
but I dont understand what this line means `int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;`

```
private static int findDuplicate(int[] array) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = array.length - 1;

        while (low <= high) {
            int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
            System.out.println(mid);
            int midVal = array[mid];

            if (midVal == mid)
                low = mid + 1;
            else
                high = mid - 1;
        }
        return high;
    }
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Answer (score 145, accepted):

The `>>>` operator is the [unsigned right bit-shift operator in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).  It effectively divides the operand by `2` to the power of the right operand, or just `2` here.

The difference between `>>` and `>>>` would only show up when shifting negative numbers.  The `>>` operator shifts a `1` bit into the most significant bit if it was a `1`, and the `>>>` shifts in a `0` regardless.

**UPDATE:**

Let's average `1` and `2147483647` (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`).  We can do the math easily:

```
(1 + 2147483647) / 2 = 2147483648 / 2 = 1073741824
```

Now, with the code `(low + high) / 2`, these are the bits involved:

```
          1: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
+2147483647: 01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
================================================
-2147483648: 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  // Overflow
/2
================================================
-1073741824: 11000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  // Signed divide, same as >> 1.
```

Let's make the "shift" to `>>>`:

```
          1: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
+2147483647: 01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
================================================
-2147483648: 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  // Overflow
>>> 1
================================================
+1073741824: 01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  // Unsigned shift right.
```

Comment: @can you illustrate with an example please. that would be very helpful

Comment: Thanks for the great illustration. but in this case `(low+high)/2` and `low + high >>> 1`, how are they equivalent?

Comment: In Java, they aren't equivalent in the case of overflow, as I have illustrated.

Comment: when the overflow occurs, with the unsigned right bit-shift operator, it technically divides by 2 and negates the sign?

Comment: Yes, the `>>>` treats the value as unsigned.  If the value was unsigned, then no overflow would have occurred.  When shifted, the value is no longer over the maximum `int` value and it can be interpreted correctly as a signed value again.

Comment: other languages get away with only the `>>` operator because they support unsigned integers and infer which behaviour to use, either the "zero filling" behaviour for unsigned, or the sign extending behaviour when used with signed inputs

As Java does not support specifying unsigned types, you instead need to specify the unsigned operator when needing to access the unsigned right shift behaviour.

Answer (score 72):

The significance of

```
int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
```

is; by using the unsigned shift, it avoids overflows which result in a negative number.  This is needed as Java doesn't support `unsigned int` values. (BTW `char` is unsigned)

The traditional way to write this was

```
int mid = (low + high) / 2; // don't do this
```

however this could overflow for larger sums and you get a negative number for the mid.

e.g.

```
int high = 2100000000;
int low = 2000000000;
System.out.println("mid using >>> 1 = " + ((low + high) >>> 1));
System.out.println("mid using / 2   = " + ((low + high) / 2));
```

prints

```
mid using >>> 1 = 2050000000
mid using / 2   = -97483648
```

clearly the second result is incorrect.

Comment: +1; very observant (and appropriate) to point out unsigned-ness of char.

Comment: @peter: if I am implementing binary search, then I need `(mid=low+high)/2`, how could that be avoided?.

Comment: @peter: can you give an example to show the importance of `>>>` please

Comment: @user2708477 use `>>> 1` instead. See my example.

Comment: with the unsigned right bit-shift operator >>>, all it does it divides by 2 but when overflow occurs, it negates the sign? Thanks for the examples though..I am getting it now

Comment: @user2708477 When there is an overflow, it treats the sign as the top bit instead.

Answer (score 12):

its a bitwise operator .. It works on the bit value .
Suppose if A holds 60 then A>>>2 will give 15 (bit value  0000 1111)

Its actual name is "Shift Zero right Operator"
here the left operands value is moved right by the number of bits specified (2 in this case)  by the right operand and shifted values are filled up with zeros(0000).

Comment: I really like what you've added here. The other answers do well in explaining the result or why one would bit shift. This was very helpful in understanding the mechanics!

Comment: A much better explanation.