# signed byte type and bitwise operators in Java?

Tags: java, int, byte, bit-manipulation

quoting from [oracle website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) "byte: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive)".

here, the first two lines are valid but the last is not

```
            byte b = -128;
        byte b1 = 127;
        byte b2 = b>>>b1;//illegal
```

Q1) what is meant exactly by 8-bit signed? 128 in binary format would be 1000 0000 and -128 would need an extra bit for the negative sign, where it would fit if  all the 8 bits are occupied.

Q2) for int, there is a unsigned right shift operator, but that seems illegal with bytes, why is it so. can overflow not be prevented in case of bytes. In [case of int, it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058859/what-does-mean-in-java)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Just what it sounds like: There are 8 bits, holding 2^8 = 256 possible values.  It's signed, so the range is frmo -128 through 127 (256 values).  The most significant bit has a value of -128.
2. In Java, *binary numeric promotion* occurs with operations such as `b >>> b1`.  Both types are promoted to `int`, and the result is an `int`.  However, you can explicitly cast the result back to `byte`.

Here's the cast:

```
byte b2 = (byte) (b >>> b1);
```

The [JLS, Section 5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2), talks about binary numeric promotion:

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or
>   both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>
> Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted
>   to float.
>
> Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted
>   to long.
>
> **Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: thanks, in terms of 8-bits, where does the sign go? `+` and `-` should be part of 8-bit right?

Comment: Think of the value of the `byte` as the sum of the values of all 8 bits: -128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, and/or 1.

Comment: That means a 8-bit representation of 1000 0000 should be -128? and not  128.?

Comment: Right, `-128` is represented as `1000 0000`, and `127` is represented as `0111 1111`.  That also means that `-1` is represented as `1111 1111`.

Comment: thanks for clearing out. but since you mentioned `-1` is represented as 1111 1111`, I am confused there. please clear this out. Thank you!

Comment: '-128' is '1000 0000', from there you count back to zero like this: '-127' is '1000 0001', '-126' = '1000 0010', '-125' = '1000 0011', .. '-1' is '1111 1111', '0' is '0000 0000'

Comment: There is one problem with the given answer.  If `b` is negative (has its most significant bit set), the resultant byte will be filled with 1s in `b1` high-order places, because `b` is sign-extended to 32 bits before the shift takes place.  To achieve the expected behavior of zero-filling high order bits, you need to do this: `byte b2 = (byte) ((b & 0xff) >>> b1);` (note that you can use `>>` interchangeably in this case because the sign bit is always 0).

Comment: @DavidM.Lloyd That would effectively treat the `byte` `b` as unsigned, because if the shift amount `b1` is `1`, then the result is `64`, not `-64`.