# Find index in array based on given value

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have a sorted array of numbers with array length as `n`. For a given item `k` find index `i` in the sorted array where elements from index `i` to `n` are greater than the given item `k`. If there is no index present then return `-1`

This is my program:

```
public static int getIndex(int[] arr, int k) {
     int x = -1;
     for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
       if(arr[i] > k) {
           x = i; break;
       }
     }
     return x;
}
```

The time complexity of this approach is O(n), and I want to reduce it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the array is sorted, use binary search for a time complexity of `O(log N)`.

```java
public static int getIndex(int[] arr, int k) {
    int low = 0, high = arr.length - 1;
    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = low + high >>> 1;
        if(arr[mid] > k) high = mid - 1;
        else low = mid + 1;
    }
    return low == arr.length ? -1 : low;
}
```

Comment: In this line `low + high >>> 1` what the 3 arrows indicate, how they work.

Comment: @learner It is the same as adding low and high, then dividing by 2, but it avoids overflow issues.

Comment: @learner : [what does ">>>" mean in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19058859/12567365)