# Check sorted non sequential array for duplicates using binary search?

Tags: c, arrays, duplicates, binary-search

I've a ***sorted array*** but it's ***not necessarily sequential***, and I need to know **IF it contains any duplicates**.

```
Array : | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 8 | 8 |
```

I know we can linearly traverse in O(n) check if it contains any duplicates, but I was wondering if it is possible using Binary Search.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binary Search O(log n) algorithm to find duplicate in sequential list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372385/binary-search-olog-n-algorithm-to-find-duplicate-in-sequential-list)

Comment: No way you can do it in less than O(N)

Comment: @ARBY The requirement of "not necessarily sequential" is invalidating the answers in the linked question. Otherwise it can be done even in O(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You can't do it with binary search. All algorithms will take at least linear time.

Comment: Thanks :)
I've one more question. If I were to run two parallel search pointers on same array (one from beginning and one from end), would that be less than a O(n) search, since I'm scanning two halves at same time.

Comment: O(n/2)=O(n). Constant factors are irrelevant for big-O notation.